# Trouble with two equations with 4 unknowns

Tags: diophantine-equations, systems-of-equations

I was wondering if I could receive assistance for the following system:

$$\begin{cases}(x/a)^{3.2}+(y/b)^{3.2}=1\\ a/b = 174.1/86\end{cases}$$ 
I'm looking for integer solutions or how to find them (if possible).

Edit: I have currently gotten this far:

$$\begin{cases} ((86x)^{3.2}+y^{3.2})/(174.1b)^{3.2}=1 \end{cases}$$
Thanks in advance!
Ken

Comment: There is no only solution. The second equation yields $a=\frac{174.1}{86}b$, substitute this in the first equation.

Comment: The tag Diophantine means you are looking for integer solutions ?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Yes, I'm looking for integer solutions or how to find them (if possible).

Comment: Including $x=0$, $y = b$ and $x=a$, $y=0$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael $$ x ≠ 0, y ≠ 0 $$ Sorry but I have don't have information regarding $$ y = b, x = a $$

Comment: I didn't mean $y=b,x=a$.  I meant there are two solutions: #1 with $x=0, y=b$, #2 with $x=a, y=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the equation for $a/b$.  There is no solution of the first equation in integers $a,b,x,y$  with $x, y \ne 0$.

You want $r = x/a$ and $s = y/b$ to be nonzero rational numbers, with $r^{16/5} + s^{16/5} = 1$.  Let $r^{1/5} = t$ and $s^{1/5} =  u$, so that  $t^{16} + s^{16} = 1$.  By a case of Fermat's Last Theorem, it is known that
this has no rational solutions with $s,t\ne 0$.  So at least one of $t$ and $u$ is irrational.  WLOG assume  $t$ is irrational, i.e. $r$ is not the $5$'th power of a rational number.  Now the same is true of $r^{16}$.  It can be shown for any rational $y$ that is not the $5$'th power of a rational, the polynomial $X^5 - y$ is irreducible.  So $u = t^{16}$, a root of the polynomial $X^5 - r^{16}$, has the minimal polynomial $X^5 - r^{16}$.

Now $s^{16} = (1 - r^{16/5})^5 = (1 - t^{16})^5 = (1-u)^5$, and thus
$(X-1)^5 + s^{16}$ is a different monic polynomial of degree $5$ with $u$ as a root.  That contradicts the assertion that $X^5 - r^{16}$ is the minimal polynomial of $u$.

We conclude that no such solution is possible.

Comment: Thank you sir! I appreciate your time and knowledge very much.