# Solving for $x$ after simplifying, please check my work!

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was presented with the question:
$$(\frac{x}{a})^{3.2} + (\frac{y}{b})^{3.2} = 1$$

While:
$$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{174.1}{86}=c$$

I began to simplify and reached:
$$x = c(b^{3.2}-y^{3.2})^{1/3.2}$$
$$y = \frac{(a^{3.2} - x^{3.2})^{1/3.2}}{c}$$
My goal is to solve for $x$.
Thus, I substituted $y$:
$$x = c(b^{3.2}-(b^{3.2}-((\frac{x^{3.2}}{c^{3.2}})^{1/3.2})^{3.2})^{1/3.2}$$
I then simplify:
$$x = c(b^{3.2}-(b^{3.2}-(\frac{x^{3.2}}{c^{3.2}}))^{1/3.2}$$ 
How should I proceed?
I am looking for $x =$

Comment: @MonkeyKing I am looking to actually come up with a numerical answer for $x$ in this question.

Comment: Suspiciously similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1248856/trouble-with-two-equations-with-4-unknowns/1248993#1248993 although that one was looking for integer solutions.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes that's me, I didn't complete the registration process and couldn't log back in so I actually created an account.  
The questions I asked before were phrased incorrectly and this is to make up for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only one equation involving $x$ and $y$.  You can't possibly eliminate $y$ from it.

Comment: Ah I see, silly mistake!  
I think a better way to word my question would be:  
How can I solve for $x$ given the following?
$$(\frac{x}{174.1})^{3.2} + (\frac{y}{86})^{3.2} = 1$$

Comment: You can't.  That's a curve in the $x-y$ plane.

Comment: Just to confirm, I would plot this curve by solving for $x$ when giving values for $y$? Thanks for your response!

Comment: I've plotted the curve and all is good! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step:

$$b^{3.2}-\left(b^{3.2}-\left(\frac{x^{3.2}}{c^{3.2}}\right)\right)
 = \frac{x^{3.2}}{c^{3.2}},$$

so

$$\left(b^{3.2} - \left(b^{3.2} - 
      \left(\frac{x^{3.2}}{c^{3.2}}\right)\right)\right)^{1/3.2}
 = \left(\frac{x^{3.2}}{c^{3.2}}\right)^{1/3.2}
 = \frac xc.$$

When you multiply this by $c$, you get $x$. So when you found that

$$x = c\left(b^{3.2} - \left(b^{3.2} 
- \left(\frac{x^{3.2}}{c^{3.2}}\right)\right)\right)^{1/3.2},$$

you just found a fancy way to write $x = x$.